# ES6: transfer nested array into array with objects using destructuring

Tags: javascript

I'm learning ES6 Destructuring and try to figure out different ways to convert a nested array with 2 numbers as elements (eg. x and y coordinates) into an array of objects just using destructuring.

```
const points = [
  [4, 5],
  [3, 12],
  [9, 30]
]

// goal: transfer to this format:
// [
//   {},
//   {},
//   {}
// ]
```

one (and probably) the best solution:

```
points.map(([ x, y ]) => {
  return { x, y };
});
```

another attempt:

```
points.map(pair => {
  const x = pair[0],
  const y = pair[1]
});

// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token const
```

Why do I get an SyntaxError here?

With:

```
points.map(pair => {
  const [ x, y ] = pair;
});
```

I get an array with 3 undefined elements. Why?

Comment: That's an invalid multiple assignment statement. You don't need the extra `const` in the second assignment.

Comment: Why you think `const x = ..., const y = ...` would be valid syntax? `.map()` has to return the new value but you only return a value in the first example and not in the second or third

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one line the return is automatic.

**One:**

```
points.map(([ x, y ]) => ({ x, y }));
```

**Two:**

```
points.map(pair => ({x: pair[0], y: pair[1]}));
```

Or in multiple lines:

```
points.map(pair => {
  const x = pair[0];
  const y = pair[1];
  return {x, y};
});
```

**Three:**

```
points.map(pair => {
  const [ x, y ] = pair;
});
```

Comment: Correction to your first example: should be `points.map(([ x, y ]) => ({ x, y }));`. Without parentheses it's considered a function block that returns nothing.